# Android Application Preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

Hi I have created an application which works good.  However I would like a preference where the user can change the text size of the main application.  The main app only consists of one view.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please check out your previous questions, provide updates and accept some answers. You history is not looking to good

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to all of this.  I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this several different ways. Define multiple layouts with different attributes for android:textSize on your TextView's and EditText's, Or use one layout and go through and call myTextView.setTextSize(someInt); on each of your views. You could store the int in sharedPreferences. @Nanne is right you need to work on your accept rate. Or people will be less willing to help you.